# Generic method performs implicit cast while non-generic method needs explicit cast

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, unchecked-conversion

This question is related [to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538370/why-does-a-local-variable-influences-type-inference-equality-constraints). The original can be solved by adding casts to do unchecked conversions. So now I have the following code:

```
import java.util.EnumSet;

class A {
    static enum E1 {
    X
    }

    private static <T extends Enum<T>> EnumSet<T> barEnum(Class<T> x) {
        return null;
    }

    private static void foo1(EnumSet<E1> s, E1 e) {
        EnumSet<E1> x2 = barEnum((Class<E1>)e.getClass());
    }

    private static void foo2(EnumSet<E1> s) {
        EnumSet<E1> x = barEnum((Class<E1>)s.iterator().next().getClass());
    }
}
```

My original intent was to write a generic method. So I generalized the method `foo2()` to:

```
private static <E extends Enum<E>> void foo3(EnumSet<E> s) {
    EnumSet<E> x = barEnum(s.iterator().next().getClass());
}
```

This obviously contains unchecked conversions and compiles with the appropriate warning. But I don't cast the result of `getClass()` explicitly into `Class<E>`. Since `foo1()` is one instance of the generic method `foo3()`, I expected that I need to add the cast here too. Comparing `foo1()` to `foo4()`...

```
    private static void foo4(EnumSet<E1> s) {
        EnumSet<E1> x = barEnum(s.iterator().next().getClass());
    }
```

...the two are effectively similar (*the main difference being the `E1 e` parameter in `foo1()`*). However `foo1()` compiles, but `foo4()` does not compile. I feel that this is inconsistent. Are there any rules allowing implicit conversions for generic methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things happening. First of all if you look at the javadoc for `getClass` it will say:

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which `getClass` is called.

That means that in your generic method, `barEnum` is invoked with a `Class<? extends Enum>` instead of a `Class<? extends Enum<E>>`. Since `Enum` is a raw type, this creates an unchecked invocation, which in turn means that the return type is erased (see also: [Why is generic of a return type erased when there is an unchecked conversion of a method parameter in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918308)).

So in that case `barEnum` is effectively returning a `EnumSet`, which is a raw type that can be converted unchecked to `EnumSet<E>`.

For your non-generic method you'd have to explicitly cast the argument to a `Class<E1>`, so there is no unchecked conversion of the method arguments and thus no unchecked invocation. But, that also means that the return type is not erased and the compiler can not find a `T` that is valid for that call.

Comment: Shouldn't `getClass()` return `Class<? extends E1>`?

Comment: @shmosel Yes it should. But isn't that the reason why I have to add the cast to `Class<E1>` in the non-generic method, as mentioned in the last paragraph?

Comment: @Jens Makes sense. Have you tried assigning it to `EnumSet<? extends E1>`?

Comment: @shmosel I'm not sure what you mean? In `foo3` `getClass` returns a `Class<? extends Enum>` and in `foo4` a `Class<? extends E1>`.

Comment: @Jens I'm referring to `foo4`.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to read the excellent Java Generics FAQ:
http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html

Off the top of my head, it won't compile because static methods don't inherit the type parameters of a generic class. Then, you're trying to get runtime class information of a parametrised type, which won't work because Java uses erasure for its generics implementation.

Generics in Java are not at all easy, once you move beyond simple collections and such. This is why the FAQ is an indispensable resource.

Answer (score 0):

When I extract a variable for the obtained Class and let my IDE 'fix' everything it can, I get this:

```
private static void foo4(Iterable<E1> s) {
    Class<? extends E1> aClass = s.iterator().next().getClass();
    EnumSet<E1>         x      = barEnum(aClass);
}
```

As you see, `aClass` is unparametrized (there is a warning on `Enum` saying that it is 'raw'). Moreover it states it can be any subclass of Enum, whereas `barEnum` accepts only a specific enum, and since specific enums are `final` classes (they can't have subclasses) there is a conflict.

When I then change `batEnum` to

```
private static <T extends Enum<T>> EnumSet<T> barEnum(Class<? extends T> x) {
```

the error goes away since now it accepts subclasses of `Enum`.

Comment: Because of dynamic linking, even `final` classes can have subclasses at runtime. So specific enums being `final` shouldn't matter. It seems to be a problem of the compiler not being able to infer `T` (since there is no valid `T` for the original call). But your solution is correct.